# Is it possible to split a polygon-subwatershed with a gage point without v.overlay?

Tags: grass-gis, overlay, r.watershed

After creating a clean map of subwatersheds I want to split some where control gages are located. If I try to do this with v.overlay (AND) - clipping subwatersheds previously generated with r.basins by clean basins generated with r.watershed, many sliver polygons are created (because r.basins and r.watersheds are different methods of delineating). I try to get rid of these sliver subwatersheds by settin a very high snap (90 meters for my DEM is enough), but in that case program stucks for a very long time when it tries to snap boundaries.

Comment: The best way to do this is run `r.water.outlet` for each gage station.

Comment: Hm.. But after that it would be necessary to make overlay, because subwatershed edges won't be identical, isn't it? I'd like to get a unite subwatershed layer

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have read the docs. r.watershed method is used, so edges should be identical. I will try it out.